# scp permission denied when a user does scp command for owned files on his home directory

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, scp

I have checked many postings regarding 'Permission denied' error in using `scp`, but couldn't find the answer for my problem.

There are two ubuntu servers (let's say server 'A' and 'B') on the same network in AWS, and when I tried to copy one file to another server, A to B is not working, but from B to A works. (Please see below)

On Server 'A',

```
ubuntu@server-a ~ $ ls -alt server*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu 8152 Aug  9 14:26 server.xml.bak

ubuntu@server-a ~ $ scp -P 443 server.xml.bak ubuntu@172.31.34.55:/home/ubuntu/
Permission denied (publickey).
lost connection

ubuntu@server-a ~ $ scp -P 443 /home/ubuntu/server.xml.bak ubuntu@172.31.34.55:/home/ubuntu/
Permission denied (publickey).
lost connection
```

Also I tried to copy the remote file to here, and it failed as well.

```
ubuntu@server-a ~ $ scp -P 443 ubuntu@172.31.34.55:/home/ubuntu/sakila.sql .
Permission denied (publickey).
```

But from Server 'B', all worked.

```
ubuntu@server-b ~ $ scp -P 443 ubuntu@172.31.45.112:/home/ubuntu/server.xml.bak .
server.xml.bak                                                    100% 8152     8.0KB/s   00:00

ubuntu@server-b ~ $ scp -P 443 sakila.sql ubuntu@172.31.45.112:/home/ubuntu/
sakila.sql                                                        100% 3153KB   3.1MB/s   00:00
```

As you see, it is not the permission issue - all operations were done by 'ubuntu' on 'ubuntu' home and files are also owned by 'ubuntu' with 755 mode.

So now I'm confused what is wrong.

Comment: Just to make sure, have you generated/copied a SSH private key on server A for user 'ubuntu' and then exported the corresponding public key counterpart to server B?

Comment: The permission error comes from failed authentication, not from file permissions. Is there an SSH daemon listening on that port on the server?

Comment: @lgeorget, I got a hint from your comment - I ran the command with `scp -v` and found it's due to missing priv key. For security reason I removed all priv keys on servers and use Pageant instead for priv key management. I've connected B (bastion server), and opened another PuTTY terminal, connected B there again, and then connect A via ssh. So B to A works (Pageant manages priv key for B) but A to B didn't work... I upload priv key to A for testing and then scp command from A also works. Since I can't keep priv key on servers, I think I should only use scp command on B.

Comment: Glad you could solve your problem! You can answer your own question and mark the answer as accepted in case it helps someone else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested, I move my original comment to the answer with more details in case anyone may have a similar issue.

I got a hint from @lgeorget 's comment - I ran the command with `scp -v` and found it's due to missing private key.

For security reason, I removed all private keys on servers and use Pageant instead for private key management. In this scenario, I connected to B (B is a bastion server) using PuTTY, opened another PuTTY terminal, connected to B again, and then connected to A via ssh. Therefore the Pageant can handle the private key for B but cannot for A directly (I couldn't recognize this)
The result is, scp command from B to target server A works but scp from A to target server B doesn't work.

I upload the private key to A for testing and then scp command from A also works fine.

Since I can't keep private keys on servers, I think I should only use scp command on server B.